# How to copy favorites of chromium and other documents from the windows partition

Tags: chromium

I did a research but I didn't find any easy to understand answer.
How to copy the favorites of chromium and other files by being in the windows partition?
If it is not possible how to do it with the terminal as I can just access it from the login menu.

added:
My ubuntu is broken and I can't access it, for this I need to retrieve the data from the windows partition or from the terminal I can access from the login menu, thank you.

Thank you

Comment: Would it not be easier to set up synch inside the browser?

Comment: My ubuntu is broken and I can't access it, for this I need to retreive the data from the windows partition or from the terminal I can access from the login menu, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

start up ubuntu and browse to your windows install than find your chrome install and copy your browsers favourite folder to linux would that work?

Comment: If you need to ask then please use the comments. This is not an answer.

Comment: My ubuntu is broken and I can't access it, for this I need to retreive the data from the windows partition or from the terminal I can access from the login menu, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Ubuntu live and use that to access your Ubuntu partition and retrieve the data. It should be in

```
[your Ubuntu partition home folder]/.config/chromium/
```

See [ubuntu live](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) for help booting Ubuntu live